# Return empty string if object null

Tags: c#, linq

The object i is from database.
PrDT is a string, PrDateTime is DataTimeOffset type, nullable

```
vi.PrDT = i.PrDateTime.Value.ToString("s");
```

What is the quick way?
I don't want if else etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
vi.PrDT = i.PrDateTime.HasValue ? i.PrDateTime.Value.ToString("s") :
                                  string.Empty;
```

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis - Pretty much.

Comment: No, if else are both blocks and this is an expression

Comment: @Oded "What happens if PrDateTime is null?" The same question applies to your code right now as well

Comment: @Esailija - an if/else can be constructed without braces, and the IL that would be generated between the two is so similar tas to be considered identical.

Comment: @MatthewCox - No, it doesn't. `PrDateTime` is a `DateTime?` - `HasValue` will either be `true` or `false`.

Comment: @MatthewCox If PtrDateTime is a nullable DateTime it cannot be null.  Nullable types are value types.

Comment: @MatthewCox we meant to say PrDateTime.Value is null, PrDateTime won't be null because its a Nullable type.

Comment: @KeithS No my point is, if you say it's the same as `if-else`, you confuse some people when they expect statements to work within `?:`. `if-else` always allows statements, even when you leave braces out, is my point.

Comment: I overlooked that little piece =P

Comment: @MatthewCox - A Nullable can be *assigned* null, but it is never a null reference. As such, HasValue is guaranteed to work.

Comment: he can use an if/else or a conditional..hell he can even use an extension method...the point is to check HasValue

Answer (score 5):

You can do an extensions method:

```
public static class NullableToStringExtensions
{
    public static string ToString<T>(this T? value, string format, string coalesce = null)
        where T : struct, IFormattable
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return coalesce;
        }
        else
        {
            return value.Value.ToString(format, null);
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
vi.PrDT = i.PrDateTime.ToString("s", string.Empty);
```

Comment: There's an if..else in there, but this seems to be the fastest way (reusable) to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Format("{0:s}", i.PrDateTime)
```

The above will return back an empty string if it's null. Since `Nullable<T>.ToString` checks for a null value and returns an empty string if it is, otherwise returns a string representation (but can't use formatting specifiers). Trick is to use string.Format, which allows you to use the format specifier you want (in this case, `s`) and still get the `Nullable<T>.ToString` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
return (i.PrDateTime.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString();
```

Just tested and it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
return i.PrDateTime.Value.ToString("s") ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: to be clear it fails if `i.PrDateTime.Value` is null, not `i.PrDataTime`, but I don't even understand this syntax...how can ToString("s") ever return a null..